# I am changing from CSM BIOS mode to UEFI BIOS mode. Is it safe?

Tags: windows, bios, uefi

I have been told by a professional that choosing uefi mode in BIOS from CSM mode in BIOS is safe.

Because in device manager it says that my system is in UEFI mode, I have 2 pictures showing the boot priority before enabling UEFI, and after.

I need help seeing if it is actually safe.

After:
[image: after]

Before:
[image: before]

Answer (score 0):

CSM Mode in Firmware (UEFI (Still being called as BIOS)) does not mean only CSM, it generally means UEFI + CSM. With CSM On your system is capable of booting either Legacy mode (MBR) as well as UEFI Mode based on the bootloader, however generally UEFI takes priority.

You say that your Windows is installed in UEFI Mode, so it will not harm anything. Just that once you switch your Firmware option to UEFI, no more Legacy Boot would be allowed and if there was any OS installed in CSM mode, it will not boot.

In a very very rare case you might get a black screen, but such instances are very rare.

What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

I always keep it CSM with UEFI so that older rescue disks that are not UEFI compatible can also be booted if required, while my main OS is always in UEFI mode.

I am not too sure if Device Manager shows you the install mode. However you can come to know if your Windows is installed in UEFI or BIOS(Legacy Mode) by running `msinfo32.exe` and looking for the parameter named `BIOS Mode`.